# Disable Google cast

Tags: samsung, chromecast

I'm having a problem where my phone will ask me to connect to a non-existent chromecast when watching something on YouTube or Netflix. It'll show a popup asking me to enter a pin and when I close that menu it just opens another right away. It seems to be triggered by hitting the volume buttons.

My phone is an S7 edge and I'm running Android 6.0.1. I don't have a chromecast connected to my internet so it shouldn't be automatically trying to connect to one. I've cleaned my phone's screen and removed the case, but it's still happening.

How can I fix this problem, or just disable connecting to chromecasts entirely?

---

This appears to be caused by Netflix. I didn't use it for about a week and no chromecast popup appeared in any app. I opened it recently and then it started happening again.

Comment: I've had this problem too when I was a guest in an apartment complex; I guess somebody nearby had a chromecast. It was super frustrating because there is no option on the box that pops up to not connect! How stupid is that.